# How to tell if function exists in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Given the following Javascript, how can I do the same in Typescript without getting an error?

```
if (typeof customizeHttpRequest === 'function') { customizeHttpRequest(xhr); }
```

I feel like this should be possible, or at least be able to suppress the error for this line.

Comment: Typescript is just a super set of Javascript. It means that you can use that check condition in Typescript too.

Comment: what error are you getting? It looks right to me already, and that's how I test for optional callback functions.

Comment: Cannot find name "customizeHttpRequest" which makes sense since it is not declared.

Comment: @jbassking10 - you will get compile time error only in Typescript, no need to check if function exist or not. If it exist then there will no compile time error. If it is not that simple. let me know your scenario

Comment: I understand how Typescript works and how Javascript works. What I want to do is eliminate the error which I don't think is possible.
The only way I could think of doing this without getting an error would be to look for the function by name - string name. However, I don't think any methods exist to do that.

Comment: How exactly are you calling the function if it isn't declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding // @ts-ignore will ignore the following line, which in my case suppresses the error. For now, this is acceptable.

```
// @ts-ignore
if (typeof customizeHttpRequest === 'function') { customizeHttpRequest(xhr); }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that `customizeHttpRequest` will always be a function, you can simply check for its existence:

`if (customizeHttpRequest) { customizeHttpRequest(xhr); }`

Comment: This is what I currently have an will generate an error.

Comment: Can you share the error? The approach will work, but depending on your typescript config you might have some rule not allowing you to use it.
The easiest way will be to try `if (customizeHttpRequest as any) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Given that you might have a `customizeHttpRequest` function not defined anywhere in the same scope than your own code I'd assume where talking about JavaScript run in the browser? If this is the case then the function, if exists, can be found from the `window` object which can be patched to define these globals that appear when including a library.

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    readonly customizeHttpRequest?: Function;
  }
}

if (typeof window.customizeHttpRequest === 'function') {
  window.customizeHttpRequest();
}
```